# i want to count number of time stat is true and count number of dates repeated against unique IDs

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, counter, listobject

using id have to make a counter for stat and ttrf and create new data with name, id, number of stat and number of ttrf repeated against unique ID

```
data = [
0: {id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}
1: {id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}
2: {id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "false", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}
3: {id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}]
```

**Output to be obtained:**

```
data = [
0: {id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: 1, ttrf: 2}
1: {id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: 2, ttrf: 2}]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve you problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i've used `reduce` method to solve this issue. You can check this solution.

```js
const data = [
  { id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020" },
  { id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020" },
  { id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "false", ttrf: "05/08/2020" },
  { id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020" },
];

const newData = data.reduce((store, obj) => {
  const statVal = obj.stat === "true" ? 1 : 0;
  const ttrfVal = obj.ttrf ? 1 : 0;
  if (!store[obj.id]) {
    store[obj.id] = obj;
    obj.ttrfDates = new Set();
    obj.ttrfDates.add(obj.ttrf);
    store[obj.id].ttrf = ttrfVal;
    store[obj.id].stat = statVal;
  } else {
    if (!(obj.stat === "true" && store[obj.id].ttrfDates.has(obj.ttrf))) {
      store[obj.id].ttrf++;
    }
    store[obj.id].stat += statVal;
  }
  return store;
}, {});

const modifiedData = Object.values(newData).filter(
  (data) => data.ttrfDates && delete data.ttrfDates
);

console.log(modifiedData);
```

Comment: Hey there Sifat, I wonder if there is an option to count days as well however I want to count one date only once.

Comment: Example => data = [
    0: {id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "false", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}
    1: {id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/09/2020"}               
    2: {id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/09/2020"}                  
   3: {id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/010/2020"}]

Comment: there are dates repeating in it as 05/09/2020. I want them to be counted only once not twice against stat: "True" and the same ID. Looking forward to your assistance.

Comment: No its not !! it's ignoring all other values.

Comment: the number of stats 'TRUE' against each data is to be counted. Example => if I get 3 stats on 12 of MAY daily counter will be 1. if I get 6 more stats on 14th of MAY,  daily counter will become 1+1 = 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785210/how-to-create-a-date-counter-i-tried-it-using-reduce-function @Sifat

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! To get what you want, you just need to create a [reduce function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp). Here are an example:

```js
data = [
{id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}
{id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}
{id: "51a", name: "Henry", team: "SPP", stat: "false", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}
{id: "5ea", name: "James", team: "BOPS", stat: "true", ttrf: "05/08/2020"}]

const formatted = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.id]) {
    acc[item.id] = { 
      id: item.id,
      name: item.name,
      team: item.team,
      stat: 0,
      origianlTtrf: item.ttrf,
      ttrf: 1
    };
  }

  if (item.stat) {
    acc[item.id].stat++;
  } 

  if (item.ttrf !== acc[item.id].originalTtrf) {
    acc[item.id].ttrf++;
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

Object.values(formatted); // the data you want in an array
```